Getting Exception in Tkinter callback error
Was implementing chatgpt on Raspberry Pi-4, using Google voice recognizer. When I run the code, it is able to take input from microphone and display it but showing the error after that. Error it is showing:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/tkinter/_init__.py", line 1948, in __call_
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/youngovator/rpichatgpt/search.py", line 14, in info
    chat = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/youngovator/rpichatgpt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_resources/chat_completion.py", line 25, in create
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/youngovator/rpichatgpt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py", line 153, in create
    response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/youngovator/rpichatgpt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 298, in request
    resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/youngovator/rpichatgpt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 700, in _interpret_response
    self._interpret_response_line(
  File "/home/youngovator/rpichatgpt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py", line 765, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.RateLimitError: You exceeded your current quota, please check your plan and billing details. For more information on this error, read the docs: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.

The code:
import speech_recognition as sr
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import time
from tkinter import *


def audio():
    # Record Audio
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
      print("Say something!")
      r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
      audio = r.listen(source)
      data = r.recognize_google(audio)
      print(data)

    return data



def speak(audiostring):
    tts=gTTS(text=audiostring,lang="en")
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    os.system("mpg321 audio.mp3")

import os
from ai import audio,speak
import openai
openai.api_key = 'KEY'
messages = [ {"role": "system", "content": "You are an intelligent assistant." } ]
def info():

    message=audio().replace(" ","")

    messages.append(
        {"role": "user", "content": message},
    )

    chat = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=messages
    )

    reply = chat.choices[0].message

    print("Assistant: ", reply.content)
    speak(reply.content)

    messages.append(reply)

from tkinter import *
from search import info


win = Tk()
win.geometry('320x50');win.title('Freedomtech Player')
button = Button(win, text="Speak", command = info )
button.pack()
win.mainloop()

I tried logging in on openai platform with different gmail accounts as it was showing 'exceeded your current quota', but for the very first run only it was showing the same error.
